# Differential equation $x^3+(y')^3-3x(y')=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This exercise in (non linear ODE. of first order and higher degree )

Solve the Differential equation

$x^3+(y')^3-3x(y')=0$

$3x(y')=x^3+(y')^3$

$3x=x^3 (y')^{-1}+(y')^2$

I think to let $t=y'$ (parameter)

$3x=x^3t^{-1}+t^2$

But then I don't know to Derivative for $t$ or for $x$ or for $y$ ?

How can I complete it:(

Comment: what is $p$ here?

Comment: @AbhishekHalder sorry I edited it, $p={dy\over dx}$, thanks.

Comment: @ Dima : $x^3+(y')^3-3x(y')=0$ his is a separable ODE. So, first solve it for $y'$ in order to obtain $y'=f(x)$ which is a complicated fonction. Second, integrate for $y=\int f(x)dx$ if you can. Probably, you cannot because nobody can find a closed form of the antiderivative of such a complicated function.

Comment: is this problem really from an exercise sheet?

Comment: @Dima Are you sure this is the exact problem? Because, if so, and if there is some invertible function $f$ such that $$p=y'=f(x)$$ then you can conclude from the symmetry of the equation that $$x=f(p)$$ and this means $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are equal. So $p=f(x)=x$ is the only solution, but obviously this doesn't satisfy the original equation. Although, you might say there maybe a non-invertible solution for $f(x)$.

Comment: Looks like exercises getting hard these days! Solving for $p$ requires solving a special cubic equation, whose solution scares me from proceeding further.